# Cloud function doesn't have permission to other projects under the same billing account to implement a spending limit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am following the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-costs to disable App Engine using cloud functions when a spending limit is reached.

I want to disable App Engine for all projects associated with the same billing account, which the docs say should work in the following note

> Note: The source code assumes that the function you are creating and the app you want to disable are in the same Google Cloud project. If the function and the app are in separate projects, change the source code so APP_NAME identifies the project that contains the app you want to disable.

But I get this error

> Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for
> termination reason. Details: <HttpError 403 when requesting
> https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/other-project?alt=json
> returned "The caller does not have permission">

I also verified that I am using the App Engine default service account with Admin role per the docs

> Select a service account that has the App Engine Admin role. The App Engine default service account has this role by default.

I modified the example for testing which is basically this

```
import base64
import json
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
APP_NAME = os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT')

def limit_use_appengine(data, context):
    pubsub_data = base64.b64decode(data['data']).decode('utf-8')
    pubsub_json = json.loads(pubsub_data)
    cost_amount = pubsub_json['costAmount']
    budget_amount = pubsub_json['budgetAmount']

    if cost_amount <= budget_amount:
        print(f'No action necessary. (Current cost: {cost_amount})')

        appengine = discovery.build(
            'appengine',
            'v1',
            cache_discovery=False
        )
        apps = appengine.apps()
    
        # for testing
        display_status(apps, APP_NAME) # works fine
        display_status(apps, "billing-account-project-name") # also works fine
        display_status(apps, "other-project") # permission error

        return

    appengine = discovery.build(
        'appengine',
        'v1',
        cache_discovery=False
    )
    apps = appengine.apps()

    check_app(apps, "APP_NAME")
    check_app(apps, "other-project")

def check_app(apps, appName):

    # Get the target app's serving status
    target_app = apps.get(appsId=appName).execute()
    current_status = target_app['servingStatus']

    # Disable target app, if necessary
    if current_status == 'SERVING':
        print(f'Attempting to disable app {appName}...')
        body = {'servingStatus': 'USER_DISABLED'}
        apps.patch(appsId=appName, updateMask='serving_status', body=body).execute()

def display_status(apps, appName):
    target_app = apps.get(appsId=appName).execute()
    current_status = target_app['servingStatus']
    print(f'Serving status for {appName} is {current_status}')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding correctly but, you are trying to disable App Engine services in different projects under the same billing account, right? As I can see in the code you shared, for the two first attempts (APP_NAME and billing-account-project-name) this is working but for  the last one (other-project) does not, right?  If this is true, I would like to know where is hosted your CF, in the billing-account-project-name project or in the other-project project.

Comment: Service Accounts either inherit permissions or are assigned permission to the project. A billing account does not affect a service account's permissions. Solution assign permission in the project for the service account where you are getting the permissions error. If you are using Organizations, assign the permission higher up so that the service account inherits permissions to projects.

Comment: Thanks @johnHanley Put this as an answer so I can mark it as the solution. I added permission in the other project to the service account used by the cloud function. It was a little tricky to understand at first how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Accounts either inherit permissions or are assigned permission to the project. A billing account does not affect a service account's permissions.

Solution: assign permission in the project for the service account where you are getting the permissions error. If you are using Organizations, assign the permission higher up so that the service account inherits permissions to projects.